# Magento 2 - Home Page Content Reorder using Set Position

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, banner-slider

I am using banner extension and the position to display banner on home page is set to Content-Top. The banner appears below category navigation on home page

**default.xml** for third party banner module

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Bannerslider" name="bannerslider.content.top" before="-">
        <action method="setPosition">
            <argument name="position" xsi:type="string">content-top</argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Now I addded below content in Home Page Content block which will display free shipping image

```
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/free-shipping.png"}}" /></p>
```

On the frontend, home page displays Banner first and then free shipping image. I tried with below code in my custom theme's `default.xml`

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="my-free-shipping-block" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">my-free-shipping-block</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
   </referenceContainer>
```

where `my-free-shipping-block` is my block identifier.

1. How do I show free shipping image first on home page followed by
   banner ?
2. Can we use `<action method="setPosition">` in our custom theme's
   **default.xml** to reorder home page content ?

Comment: remove before="-" from  default.xml from the third party code. You can customize them unless you mess them up. Remember to keep backup.

Comment: @Anime, I am making changes in my theme's `default.xml` and not in third party extension's `default.xml`.

Comment: please check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try [creating static block](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-create-and-add-a-static-block/) for your placing shipping image before your slider.

You may try following layout in your theme:

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="my-free-shipping-block-identifer" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">quikrete-free-shipping-block-identifer</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
   </referenceContainer>
```

**In above code you must use `name="block_id"`  and use the id of the static block which you will get from backend in place of `quikrete-free-shipping-block-identifer`.**

And edit the `default.xml` layout of your third party as:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Bannerslider" name="bannerslider.content.top"  after=''>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: You mean create separate free shipping cms block ? Currently I am adding it in home page block. And in which file do I need to put above snippet code ?

Comment: try the same file which you used above. i.e. default.xml and create your separate static block, it is short procedure.

Comment: ya it does the same. But, make sure that slider from your layout is executed.